# Activate class="animate__animated animate__bounce" on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, css-animations

I am learning html and css and I want to use this library: https://animate.style/

I have this code

```
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
```

https://codepen.io/wmfznuiy-the-looper/pen/jOaMXXg

NUESTROS SERVICIOS

I want the effect to work when clicking. I used this code but it didn't work

```
$("#hola").click(function() {
  $('.animate__animated .animate__bounce-active').toggleClass('.animate__animated .animate__bounce-active');
});
```

I have read many post and followed what they say but it is not working. I am new, please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### # 1: Missing jQuery.

If you open the console in your *CodePen*, you may see this kind of error:

> ***ReferenceError: $ is not defined***

This means you're using jQuery's script without importing them. You can import it whether in *CodePen*'s setting or manually import from [jQuery's CDN](https://releases.jquery.com/).

#### # 2: Fix Some Code.

Instead of this, which is find the element which has class `.animate__animated .animate__bounce-active` toggle add the class to them.

```
$('#hola').click(function () {
  $('.animate__animated .animate__bounce-active').toggleClass(
    '.animate__animated .animate__bounce-active'
  );
});
```

Change to this, which add the class to the `#hola` everytime get clicked and remove those class after a second:

```
$('#hola').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('animate__animated animate__bounce');
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).removeClass('animate__animated animate__bounce');
  }, 1000);
});
```

#### # 3: Opinion

This is the element you're targetting. After a few times trying and finding the best solution, I think `animate.style` doesn't support the animation for the anchor tag.  But it works with `<h1>` and the others. ***(Correct me if I'm wrong or missed something)***

```
<a id="hola" class="nav-link" href="#nuestros_servicios">NUESTROS SERVICIOS</a>
```

---

#### Result (in Code Snippet)

*P/s: This result is using `<h1>` instead of `<a>` tag.*

```js
$('#hola').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('animate__animated animate__bounce');
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).removeClass('animate__animated animate__bounce');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>

<h1 id="hola" class="nav-link">NUESTROS SERVICIOS</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow Thank you soooo much
I am so happy and I didn't think nobody wanted to help me because it is my first post
I had already tried a million of times and the reason all of the other codes didn't work was because of what you said. I was using the anchor tag.
Animate.style has documentation and they say the best way to do what I wanted was using this

```
const animateCSS = (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') =>
  // We create a Promise and return it
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
    const node = document.querySelector(element);

    node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);
      resolve('Animation ended');
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd, {once: true});
  });
```

but they never mentioned this was not going to work with the anchor tag and that's why It was not working. Thank you so much. I tried your solutuion and their solution and they both work but yeah I had to change it for H1. I wished I could use it with the anchor tag but that's the way it is I guess. Thanks

Comment: I modified your code like this and it worked with the anchor tag. I changed id for a class :)

 $(function(){
  $('a.hola').on('click', function(){
            $('a.hola').addClass('animate__animated animate__bounce') ;  
            setTimeout(() => {
              $(this).removeClass('animate__animated animate__bounce');
            }, 1000);

                 });
   });

I am super happy. Sorry I don't know how to copy and paste the code well. I hope you understand it